# copying strings , c++

Tags: c++, string

i'm trying to perform a program that prints string correctly from it's middle
the problem to me is that strange behavior to me that at certain line it agrees to print string only char by char and refuses to return it to be printed in the main function

here is my code :

```
string unscramble(string line)
{
    string temp;
    int i,j;
    int len=line.size();
    i=len/2-1;
    j=0;
    do{
        if(i<0)
        i=len-1;

        temp[j]=line[i];
        cout << temp[j];

        j++;
        i--;
    }while(i!=(len/2)-1);

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Provide: 1) input 2) expected output 3) actual output

Comment: Also please be precise when asking questions. "refuses to return it" means exactly what? Do you get an error, is the string empty or what exactly happens?

Comment: Are you trying to print the string in a reverse order? From the middle to start and from the end to the middle?

Comment: yes i'm trying to print it reversely from the middle 
and the string returned empty

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in the assignment to temp. You'll also hit an issue if the string length is even. Do it this way instead:

```
string unscramble(string line)
{
    string temp;
    int i, j;
    int len = line.size();
    int factor = len / 2 - 1;
    if(len % 2 == 1)
        factor = len / 2;
    i = factor;
    j = 0;
    do
    {
        if(i < 0)
            i = len - 1;
        temp += line[i];
        j++;
        i--;
    }
    while(i != factor);
    return temp;
}
```

Example input: RUT OWT SNEH HCNERF EERHTEGDIRTRAP A DNA SEVODELT

Output: THREE FRENCH HENS TWO TURTLEDOVES AND A PARTRIDGE

Comment: I'm not a huge expert on the standard library, but my guess would be that since temp has a length of 0, assignment is not possible. If temp is not empty originally, but instead has the size of line, it would work fine.

Comment: Why do think assigning char by char was wrong? It works fine!

Comment: @nielsen, not for me. Maybe it's compiler dependent. Try inputting your code here and see if it works: http://cpp.sh/

Comment: because code wasn't working unless i changed this line

Comment: Compilation successful ! suggestions for compilers :(

Comment: @Jaciq - I tried what you propsed and it worked without problem.

Comment: @Insyder - "suggestion for compilers" ? Sorry I'm lost - what do you mean?

Comment: am using codeblocks IDE and it produces error when i use 
temp[j]=line[i];
although it must go well , 
cpp.sh compiled it successfully

Comment: @Insyder_: The code in the other answer has a terrible bug and Jaciq is right. `temp` was an __empty__ `std::string` and indexing into an empty string is undefined behavior. This code uses concatenation to build the output string, which works correctly.